# Java Set Transparency on Graphics object not Color object

Tags: java, graphics, transparency, alpha

Is there any way to set the transparency of a Graphics or Graphics2D object in Java as opposed to a Color object?

Something like this is what I want:

```
graphics.setAlpha(0.5);
graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
graphics.setAlpha(1);
```

Any insight? This is a simplified version of what I'm doing, please don't reply with workarounds, I would just like to know if this is possible.

Comment: you want transparency in buttons that have images or standar components ?

Comment: We kind of need to know the components. Standard forms like `graphics.drawRect...)` can just be set like: `Color c = new Color(r,g,b,0.5f);`. Also, `0.5` is a double, add `f` to ensure it's a float.

Comment: @MauricioGracia Sorry, I wasn't clear, this has nothing to do with java components, I am simply asking is java.awt.Graphics has any way to add transparency to all graphics drawn

Comment: Also why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DJClayworth because instead of rewriting the code for all the drawing in my program to include transparancy (for a simple feature), i can just do this

Answer (score 3):

So after a few irrelevant answers and some more digging I found the solution. The [AlphaComposite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) class.

used like this:

```
Composite originalComposite = graphics.getComposite();
AlphaComposite alphaComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f);
graphics.setComposite(alphaComposite);
graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
graphics.setComposite(originalComposite);
```